# Is there a way to instantiate SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST with another SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a way to instantiate SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST with another SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST?

```
DECLARE
  V_GROUP_1 SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 2, 3, 4); -- OK
  V_GROUP_2 SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(5, 6, 7, 8); -- OK
  V_GROUP_3 SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(V_GROUP_1, V_GROUP_2); -- NOK
BEGIN
  FOR X IN V_GROUP_3.FIRST .. V_GROUP_3.LAST LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_GROUP_3(X));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [`ODCINUMBERLIST` is a `VARRAY`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/ext_types_ref.htm#sthref757) so some operations aren't allowed. The closest you can really get is to clone one variable and then append all the values from the other:

```
DECLARE
  V_GROUP_1 SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 2, 3, 4);
  V_GROUP_2 SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(5, 6, 7, 8); -- OK
  V_GROUP_3 SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST := V_GROUP_1;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..V_GROUP_2.COUNT LOOP
    V_GROUP_3.EXTEND;
    V_GROUP_3(V_GROUP_3.LAST) := V_GROUP_2(i);
  END LOOP;
  FOR X IN V_GROUP_3.FIRST .. V_GROUP_3.LAST LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_GROUP_3(X));
  END LOOP;
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

If the lists are large it may be slightly more efficient to do a single extension with `V_GROUP_3.EXTEND(V_GROUP_2.COUNT)` and then keep track of where you are inserting into (since `LAST` will always point to the end of the array). And @mottor's variation of incurring a context switch to combine the arrays through SQL is worth looking at too; you can benchmark to see which is best.

If you define your own type which is a nested table rather than a `VARRAY` - either at SQL level or in PL/SQL, depending on how and where you will refer to it - you can use [the multiset operators](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/operators006.htm):

```
CREATE TYPE NUMBERTABLE AS TABLE OF NUMBER
/

DECLARE
  V_GROUP_1 NUMBERTABLE := NUMBERTABLE(1, 2, 3, 4);
  V_GROUP_2 NUMBERTABLE := NUMBERTABLE(5, 6, 7, 8, 4);
  V_GROUP_3 NUMBERTABLE := V_GROUP_1 MULTISET UNION V_GROUP_2;
BEGIN
  FOR X IN V_GROUP_3.FIRST .. V_GROUP_3.LAST LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_GROUP_3(X));
  END LOOP;
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

If the type is declared in PL/SQL you can't use it in SQL operations; with an SQL-level type you can use the variables in table collection expressions.

Note that despite the behaviour of the normal `UNION` operator, this does not suppress duplicates by default; as the documentation shows the `ALL` is implied. If you did want to suppress duplicates you could make it `UNION DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 3):

It is easier, if you use nested tables not varrays:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE nested_typ IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

   nt1   nested_typ := nested_typ (1, 2, 3, 4);
   nt2   nested_typ := nested_typ (5, 6, 7, 8);
   nt3   nested_typ := nt1 MULTISET UNION ALL nt2;
BEGIN
   FOR X IN nt3.FIRST .. nt3.LAST
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (nt3 (X));
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Instead of UNION ALL is possible to use [MULTISET EXCEPT, INTRESECT and UNION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/operators006.htm).

And if you WANT to use varrays:

```
DECLARE
   V_GROUP_1   SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST (1, 2, 3, 4); -- OK
   V_GROUP_2   SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST (5, 6, 7, 8); -- OK
   V_GROUP_3   SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST (); -- NOK
BEGIN
   SELECT *
     BULK COLLECT INTO v_group_3
     FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE (V_GROUP_1)
           UNION ALL
           SELECT * FROM TABLE (V_GROUP_2));

   FOR X IN V_GROUP_3.FIRST .. V_GROUP_3.LAST
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (V_GROUP_3 (X));
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

You can use here [UNION, INTERSECT and MINUS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries004.htm) too.